# Blender Lamp not illuminating or reflecting in viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view, light

My blender spotlight is not illuminating over my shapes, It is properly placed but for some reason it does not display the proper effect.

[image: lights in viewport]

This is what the image is supposed to look like:
[image: what it should look like]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you please explain what "proper effect" means to you? You could add a sketch or a description of the effect you want to get.

Comment: I posted an example of what the image is supposed to look like in the original post.. I am having trouble adding a picture to my post, right now it is in the form of a link.

Comment: You need to render out the image to see full lighting and shadows. Try pressing F12.

Answer (score 4):

*(Do note this is for the Blender Internal renderer.)*

You absolutely can see lighting and shadows in the viewport. Your issue is you have the *[Viewport Shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html)* set to *Solid*. In *Solid* you do not get lighting or shadows.

Switch the Viewport Shading to either *Textured*, or *Material*. (Rendered will show the lighting too, but that is not what you want.)
Now in the properties panel under the *Shading* section set the *Material Mode* to *GLSL*.

[image: Viewport Shading and Material Mode buttons]